# Does WebSphere have a Scheduler Management Console?

Tags: console, websphere, esb, scheduler

Well the question is clear I guess, We have WebSphere ESB Server 7.5.0.1. We write some java codes to send tasks to scheduler. But what I am wondering is, Is there any scheduler management console to manage and create tasks for schedulers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.  It should be possible to write one yourself using the [WASScheduler MBean](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/WASScheduler.html).